# How can I get data from a response payload <script>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, csrf-token

Let's say I have a function that runs `fetch()` to send an asynchronous `GET` request that returns a response with the following payload:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrfToken = "ImJmMWIxZjI0ZGRmMTA1ZGVkYWQ5NThlNThlYjM3OTYzYmRhNmRiMDAiU"
</script>
```

How can I access the `csrfToken` variable in Vue?

When I access the response body it converts that whole body into a giant string rather than running the JS and making the variable available for use.

Comment: It returns the full script tag? Or does it just return the token? Either way, you could use `localStorage`. Really depends on how you have everything structured, what you're doing with this token etc.

Comment: It returns the whole script tag. I'm just trying to extract the token so I can use it in the header of my future requests

Comment: Further context on what exactly I'm trying to do can be seen in the AJAX section [here](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/csrf.html). Note that I'm using Vue and not jQuery hence why the example there is hard for me to implement

Comment: If you have control of the backend for this request, you could send the token by itself and store it in a data property from there.

Comment: Seems strange to send an entire script tag like this in a request.

Comment: Yeah I do have control of the backend as well. I initially tried to do that but there is no documentation on how to extract it and send it using the module I'm using. Maybe that should be the question I ask rather than this one though. You make a good point. I'll close this out and create another question on how to do this on the backend