# FlaskWTF how to send CSRF token to Vue front-end

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm working on an app with Vue frontend and Flask backend.

I am writing my forms in Vue but I'm trying to use FlaskWTF for CSRF/XSRF security and for form validation on the back-end.

I've wrapped my app in `CSRFProtect()` as they say to do in [the FlaskWTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html), if using AJAX.

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = build_app()
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

But I'm stuck on how to send over the CSRF token in a form that is readable for Vue. In their docs they suggest rendering a template with the following script:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

And then settings headers on future post request with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, I'm not using jQuery, and I'm stuck on how to even access the token when it's sent as a giant script tag in my response payload (see more details on this problem in [this question that I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499966/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-response-payload-script?noredirect=1#comment115802379_65499966)).

With all that in mind -- what is the best practice for handling CSRF using FlaskWTF+Vue? How should I be sending over my CSRF token and how should I be receiving it with Vue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you load up your Vue app, can you check the cookies in your browser and see if you're already receiving a CSRF cookie from Flask? Sometimes they do that by default

Comment: I noticed that actually - I do receive a cookie shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/xoNNOSD)... BUT it does not match the CSRF token that I see is sent in the response body -- so I was confused what it was for -- [CSRF response shown here](https://imgur.com/a/ReQRnql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fairly opinionated question with no "right" answer. My preference for SPAs is to do a cookie-to-header token flow, meaning your backend issues a csrf token cookie and your front-end sends it back as a header. This is a fairly prevalent pattern and fetch libraries like axios will automatically find your CSRF token cookie and append it to requests to your backend as a header.

It looks like in Flask-WTF you can generate a csrf token and add it as a cookie yourself:

```py
from flask_wtf.csrf import generate_csrf

@app.after_request
def set_xsrf_cookie(response):
    set_cookie('CSRF-TOKEN', generate_csrf())
    return response
```

At this point, you'll want to make sure you see a "CSRF-TOKEN" cookie being set from the server. If so, you're good to move on to the next step, which is sending this token back as a header.

To do so, you can configure a fetch client to always send the same token back as an `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header, but I personally like the axios fetch client because it automatically does this for you.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if FlaskWTF detects the token automatically on receiving the post request or is there some sort of manual check that needs to be performed at that point?

Comment: I _assume_ it does it automatically, a lot of frameworks do, but I don't know flask wtf that well

Comment: One more question -- why is sending it back the CSRF token as a header standard practice? Would it not be easier to just send it back as a cookie?

Comment: If you just send the cookie right back unchanged, then you don’t actually eliminate the attack vector. By forcing the client to transform the cookie to a header, you’re able to verify the client is allowed to read the cookie, which would be impossible for attackers

Comment: I have the error : "NameError: name 'set_cookie' is not defined" when i try your solution. Can you help ?

Comment: @nox - maybe try res = make_response("")
    res.set_cookie('csrf_token', csrfToken, domain = MY_WEBTOOL_DOMAIN) where res is imported like : from flask import Flask, ..., make_response